# Is there a more idiomatic phrase for "can be used in later times"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is there a more idiomatic phrase for *can be used in later times*?

For example:

> One of my demands is that the code **can be used in later times**.

Comment: Maybe just _can be reused / can be used over and over_

Comment: [Code reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse) is a well-known term, so I would say "...is that the code be reusable" or "...can be reused."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stangdon wrote in [his comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85468/how-to-write-in-a-better-english-can-be-used-in-later-times#comment165385_85468), [code reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse) is an established and well-known term.

So, instead of: *the code can be used in later times*,
you should write: *the code is **reusable*** or *the code can be **reused***.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

> One of my demands is that the code can be used **later on**.

See [later on](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/later+on):

> Adv.   1.  later on - happening at a time subsequent to a reference time